# Solve a general partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm trying to solve this PDE

> Let $f,h \in C^1(\mathbb{R^2})$. If $f_x = -h_t$ and  $g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, prove that there exists $ v \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that, for any $g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ the function $u(x,t) := g(v(x,t))$ it's solution of the equation $$fu_t + hu_x = 0.$$

I already tried to find a function $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$, with $\alpha_i : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $\alpha = (h,f)$ on this way we have that $u(\alpha(s))$ is constant, because if the apply the chain rule to the function of before $$Du(\alpha(s)) = u'(a(s)) \cdot \alpha'(s) 
= u_x(a(s))h(s) + u_t(a(s))f(s) = 0.$$

But I'm having troubles to find out the function $\alpha$ and I don't know where to use the hypothesis that $f_x = -h_t$.
Can you help me with this please?. Thanks.

Comment: You originally give $g$ as a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function on $\Bbb{R}^2$ and then (twice) assert that it is only continuous on $\Bbb{R}$.  Which is it?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. It's suppose to be h insted of g in the first assumtion.